# Python 2.7 io.open: Use "from io import open" or "io.open()"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-module

I’m working on some code that should run under both Python 2.7.x *and* Python 3.3+ unchanged, and uses Unicode data text file I/O.

So which is better—**and why?**

**Variant 1:**

```
import io
encoding = 'utf-8'

with io.open('Unicode.txt', 'w', encoding=encoding) as f:
    …
with io.open('Unicode.txt', 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
    …
```

**Variant 2:**

```
from io import open
encoding = 'utf-8'

with open('Unicode.txt', 'w', encoding=encoding) as f:
    …
with open('Unicode.txt', 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
    …
```

Personally, I’d *tend* to use Variant 2, because the code should be as Python-3-*ish* as possible, just providing backport stubs for Python 2.7.x. It also looks cleaner and I wouldn’t have to change existing code much. Also I think maybe I could save a little by not importing the whole io module.

Comment: You always import a whole module. The only difference this makes is what name is bound in your current module globals (so either `io` is bound, or `open` is bound).

Comment: Didn’t know that, thanks for the explanation, Martijn!

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is not a duplicate of the other question. It's specific to 'open'. Using Variant 2 means that you can just delete the whole import line once Python 3 has been fully adopted.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the duplicate is about general importing style, while this question was really about future-proofing the `open()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As @smido has pointed out in a comment, `open` is a built-in in both Python 2 and 3, then it is already available in both versions of Python without any imports.

Now, assuming that you are asking about what is a better way to import a package, i.e., `import module` vs `from module import ...`, formally there is no better way, it is up to you, but I think it is good to use **variant 1** since in case you will use another module that has a function called `open()`, the last import will override the former.

You are right that in general in Python 3 is very common to use `from module import field`, but I personally would use the first variant. In the end, if you are worried about typing more, a good editor or IDE would help you. :-)

Comment: `open` is a built-in in both python 2 and python 3, so you already have the open imported on both pythons. the import `from io import open` will only change what's used in python2. This is against the argument that 'you shouldn't do this because you might want to use some other `open` from other module'

Comment: @smido, thanks for the observation. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This answer is missing the whole point of the question. The question was not at all about the best import style. It was specifically about future-proofing the code. And OP's variant 2 in the option that would best future-proof the code.

Comment: The key point of this question is that Python 2's default `open()` function does not support utf-8, whereas Python 3's does, and so does `io.open`. Adding the line `from io import open` makes code look the same in Python 2 and Python 3 from that point on in the file.